# Cannot get values insight <<Some_text_here>> or <some_text_here> from MSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot get the values insight single<......> or double<<....>> symbol from mysql.

It's always return <> or <<>>.

**Mysql Data:**
[image]

**Sample Code :**

```
$sql = "SELECT id,html_form_data FROM `user_detail`";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $getFormData[] = $row;
}
print_r($getFormData);
```

**Getting Result:**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [html_form_data] => ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADNKo.png) => Array ( [id] => 2 [html_form_data] => <> ) )

**Note : I am geting the values after interchanged the <.....> into $.....$**

But I know that any reason for return it? or any ways to getting values?

Comment: wat is the data type of your database column

Comment: html_form_data is set varchar(255);

Comment: Your query is fetching data.. but your browser converts them into tags, so its missing from your view. Try with [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: you're just being deceived, its there, its just interpreted as tag since you're opening it in a browser, just like tham said, to see it., you can just use `htmlentities` or just check out the view source

Comment: htmlentities working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I earlier mentioned in the comments try printing your `$getFormData` like this:

```
array_map("printHTML", $getFormData);

function printHTML($a) {
  echo htmlentities($a)."<br/>";
}
```

**Note:** This is for your testing. This handles only one dimensional array for now.

---

**Update1:**

This handles multidimensional array:

```
function printHTML($a) {
  if(!is_array($a))
    echo htmlentities($a)."<br/>";
  else
    array_map("printHTML", $a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use codification of utf8_general_ci for that column in you DB.

Comment: I cannot get values by using utf8_general_ci.